# confunsion in create if in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a question how to make a IF

```
    for (i in 1:12){
    for (j in 1:12) {
    
    if (i != j) {
    
    var = x + b
    }
    else{ }
    
    }}
```

"else" I need that when they are equal to continue with j + 1 example: if i = 4 and j = 4 then continue with j = 5 and continue counting until the end of j and continue the process of when i! = j

Comment: You don't need the `else`. If `i==j` then R will do nothing. Instead it will simply continue the loop with the next j, i.e. j + 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't understand what is going on in your code or you don't understand what for loops do. One "trick" you can do is to actually print what happens in your for loops so that you will have one idea of what is going on. You could also do this with a piece of paper.

As they already pointed you out, you don't need the else because the for already takes care of this.

```
for (i in 1:12){
  print("-------------------------------")
  valueI <- paste0("my i value is ",i)
  print(valueI)
  for (j in 1:12) {
    valueJ <- paste0("my j value is ",j)
    print(valueJ)
    if (i != j) {
      #var = x + b
      diff <- paste0(i, " is different than ", j)
      print(diff)
    }
    else{ 
    }
  
  }
}
```

This code is the same as yours and will generate a log that explains you what happens step from step, you could also use a debugger but seeing your struggles, better use this for now. What are you trying to calculate? I feel like you want to calculate the power of something...